# Extracting XML elements with specific child element contents with Scala

Tags: xml, scala

For a XML snippet like this:

```
val fruits =
<fruits>
  <fruit>
    <name>apple</name>
    <taste>red</taste>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
    <name>banana</name>
    <taste>yellow</taste>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
    <name>banana</name>
    <taste>green</taste>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
    <name>apple</name>
    <taste>green</taste>
  </fruit>
</fruits>
```

doing something like:

```
fruits \\ "fruit"
```

will return a sequence of type `scala.xml.NodeSeq` with all the fruits and sub nodes inside.

How can I limit this sequence to contain only the fruit elements with 'banana' inside. ie, I want the result to be:

```
<fruits>
  <fruit>
    <name>banana</name>
    <taste>yellow</taste>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
    <name>banana</name>
    <taste>green</taste>
  </fruit>
<fruits>
```

Comment: the `<fruit>` tags in your expected output don't match up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(fruits \\ "fruit").filter(x =>      // filter the sequence of fruits
  (x \\ "name")                      // find name nodes
    .flatMap(_.child.map(_.text))    // get all name node text values
    .contains("banana"))             // see which name nodes contain "banana"
```

Returns the `NodeSeq`:

```
  <fruit>
    <name>banana</name>
    <taste>yellow</taste>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
    <name>banana</name>
    <taste>green</taste>
  </fruit>
```

Comment: I would use `equals` instead of `contains` but otherwise this solution is perfect.

Comment: @ChrisJamesC, the `flatMap` returns a `List[String]` in case there are multiple `<name>` nodes.  So `contains` makes sure that at least one of them says "banana".

Comment: My bad, now I understand. Thanks for the precision.